# Can we know user that is logged in our system (computer) using react

Tags: reactjs

I have three different user who can login in client and use applicaton(react) now i want to know which user is used application  at particular time.

Comment: After login, you can store their data in local storage. This way you can know which is one loggedin in any page.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya But how would you differentiate between different users based on the OS account? I don't think browsers are allowed any such liberty. This can result in some serious security and privacy issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't link your OS users with users of your application, What you should do Is to allow your application to manage their own list of users. and create authentication system where user can registered with they username and password. When each of your use need to login into the application It will used your application data.

And you should use some kind of database which will keep your application list of users permanently.

And for that you must have some Backend which will manage authentication and access of database.

You can make search about topics like building API with Express js, Mongo DB and Authentication with JWT

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to reactjs. Some related to your backend. Maybe i am not sure what you are really asking.

If your backend server need to know which user has logged in, you can store your user id, login time,... any other info. to your database.

If you want reactjs to be able to recognize the user id, last login time or any user info. throughout the entire application , you can store these info. into reactjs context or redux store for later use.